# how to run or compile golang program with Qemu in Linux BuildRoot

Tags: go, qemu, buildroot

I have a Golang program file and I want to run it in Buildroot.
I know how to compile a c file (arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc) with Qemu in BuildRoot but I don't know how to run golang file (hello.go) in buildroot.

I want to run Golang program in buildroot with Qemu